# Implementation of a function based on a recursive definition

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I am studying for a test and i came across this question. I am Computer science and  business administration student. I am a little confused on the question. Not sure if our prof wants us to write the java program of the question below

Implement the function Q (a chaotic sequence generator based on the following recursive definition

Q(N) =

- N                            if N < 3
- Q(N-Q(N-1)) + Q(N-Q(N-2))     if N>=3

Comment: what is small `n`?

Comment: @Lino sorry typo, corrected it

Comment: "Not sure if our prof wants us to write the java program" - you want us to tell you if your prof wants you to write a java program???

Comment: That's just a recurrence relation - quite easy to convert to code.

Comment: public int q(int n){
    return (n < 3)?n : q(n-q(n-1)) + q(n-q(n-2)) ;
}

Comment: "Implement the function" means exactly what it says. Assuming your course only used Java so far, it's safe to assume that you're supposed to implement it (write code) in Java. So yes, you should write a Java program.

Comment: @pkpnd thank you so much for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple Java implementation :

```
public int q(int n){
    if(n < 3) return n;
    return q(n-q(n-1)) + q(n-q(n-2)) 
}
```

Comment: Doing OP's homework for them isn't really the best way for them to learn.

Comment: maybe you're right, sorry!

Comment: @ollaw thank you that was the solution  i had as well!

Comment: And now lets calc q(100) :-)